# Is it safe to pass sessions that will be used in a prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql, session

here's my scenario:

Page 1 is the table page, all the records are displayed here.

Page 2 is the filter page, here you can choose specific records to display

The user uses Page 2 to choose what records to display on Page 1

What I want to happen is after displaying the records on Page 1 and the user clicks one of the column headers on that table, the table on Page 1 refreshes and sorts based on the column header that was clicked but still uses the same options previously selected on Page 2.

My idea is to save each options the user chooses into a session. So when the user clicks on one of the column headers to sort the table, the same filter options will be queried and I only had to add the sorting part to the statement.

I am using prepared statement, so is using sessions safe for this since I will be using prepared statement to protect from hacks/injections anyway?

Comment: just past them as post parameters. storing in the session prevents the user to properly use multiple tabs/windows.

Comment: Page 2 is the one receiving Posted variables though, if I pass them as post between pages that means I will have to make Page 1 read for posted variables too (if there are any).:( I guess if that's the best way I'll use that way :)

Comment: Is it safe though, I mean if using sessions if later they will run though as prepared statement anyway? What did you mean it prevents the user to propertly use multiple tabs/windows?

Comment: Ok I followed your suggestion and passed them as post parameters and it is perfect.:)